# Android Network Job Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I've just finished working on a multi-threaded network queue and was wondering where I could improve. I'm a little rusty when it comes to waits and such.

The idea is to queue up network actions whilst waiting for a form of network internet connectivity. I also added the ability to prioritize which network actions should be performed first. I also intend to add functionality allowing a `NetworkJob` to specify the type of connection (For those wanting to be connected to WiFi).

With that being said, my main questions are:

1. Can you see any glaring issues in the synchronized blocks and waits?
2. Can you see anywhere I could improve the code for legibility? I'm not totally sure why, but it does seem like quite a mess to me. (Though I might be being over the top.)
3. Are there any features that I've missed?

**NetworkQueue.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

/**
 * Created by Tom on 14/09/2015.
 */
public final class NetworkQueue extends Thread {

    private Context context;
    private final PriorityQueue<NetworkJob> actions;
    private volatile ConnectionType connection = ConnectionType.NONE;

    private final Object networkLock = new Object();
    private final Object actionsLock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean stop = false;

    public NetworkQueue(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.actions = new PriorityQueue<>(5, new NetworkJobComparator());
        context.registerReceiver(new NetworkListener(),
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!stop) {
                synchronized (actionsLock) {
                    if (actions.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.v("NetworkQueue", "Awaiting new job");
                        actionsLock.wait();
                        Log.v("NetworkQueue", "Received new job");
                    }
                }
                if (connection == ConnectionType.NONE) {
                    synchronized (networkLock) {
                        Log.v("NetworkQueue", "Awaiting internet connection!");
                        networkLock.wait();
                        Log.v("NetworkQueue", "Internet connection obtained!");
                    }
                }
                synchronized (actionsLock) {
                    NetworkJob job = actions.poll();
                    if (job.perform()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    actions.add(job);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addJob(NetworkJob job) {
        synchronized (actionsLock) {
            if (this.actions.contains(job)) {
                Log.v("Network Queue", "Waiting for internet connection, "
                        + job.priority() + " priority job: " + job.getClass().getSimpleName() + " already in queue.");
                return;
            }
            this.actions.add(job);
            synchronized (actionsLock) {
                this.actionsLock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public void end() {
        this.stop = false;
    }

    private class NetworkListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo == null) {
                NetworkQueue.this.connection = ConnectionType.NONE;
                return;
            }
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                NetworkQueue.this.connection = ConnectionType.WIFI;
                synchronized (networkLock) {
                    networkLock.notifyAll();
                }
                return;
            }
            NetworkQueue.this.connection = ConnectionType.ANY;
            synchronized (networkLock) {
                networkLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**NetworkPriority.java**

```
/**
 * Created by thomas on 16/09/15.
 */
public enum NetworkPriority {
    /**
     * Used when the user is sending data to the server (Responses)
     */
    HIGH,
    /**
     * Used when the user is requesting a specific resource (Usually more important)
     */
    MEDIUM,
    /**
     * Used for general requests
     */
    LOW
}
```

**NetworkJobComparator.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Created by thomas on 16/09/15.
 */
public class NetworkJobComparator implements Comparator<NetworkJob> {
    @Override
    public int compare(NetworkJob lhs, NetworkJob rhs) {
        return lhs.priority().compareTo(rhs.priority());
    }
}
```

NetworkJob.java

```
public interface NetworkJob {

    /**
     * The action requiring network connectivity
     * @return true only if the network action has succeeded.
     */
    boolean perform();

    NetworkPriority priority();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three significant items that stand out to me:

1. don't mix memory model strategies - volatile, and synchronized (and I see you removed the concurrent-based imports) all exist in your code. Typically, you only need one of them (which one it is depends on your circumstances)
2. don't override Thread, implement `Runnable` instead.
3. don't log in synchronized blocks

In addition, there are some smaller items:

1. you double-nest the synchronization on `actionLock` in the method `addJob(...)`.
2. your `end()` method sets `stop` to `false`, but it was already `false`, so your `end()` does nothing, actually..... ;p
3. you don't have enough functions - your existing functions do too much.

On the up-side:

- your enums are good
- variable names are good
- generally neat, and readable code.

So, having said the above, I would recommend your re-introduction of the `java.util.concurrent.*` classes in to your code, and ignore the synchronization and volatile aspects. A Reentrant lock and condition would be good for waiting for network availability.

```
public final class NetworkQueue implements Runnable {

    private final Context context;
    private final PriorityBlockingQueue<NetworkJob> actions;
    private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private final ReentrantLock networkLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition networkUp = networklock.newCondition();
    private ConnectionType connection = ConnectionType.NONE;

    public NetworkQueue(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.actions = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(5, new NetworkJobComparator());
        context.registerReceiver(new NetworkListener(),
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    private final void setNetwork(ConnectionType net) {
        networkLock.lock();
        try {
            connection = net;
            if (connection != Connection.NONE) {
                networkUp.signal();
            }
        } finally {
            networkLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private ConnectionType waitNetworkUp() {
        networkLock.lock();
        try {
            while (connection != Connection.NONE) {
                networkUp.await();
            }
            return connection;
        } finally {
            networkLock.unlock();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (running.get()) {
                ConnectionType current = waitNetworkUp();
                NetworkJob job = actions.take();
                if (!job.perform()) {
                    actions.add(job);
                }
            }
        } catch (......) {....}
    }

    public void end() {
        running.set(false);
    }

    ....

}
```

Note how you can use the blocking nature of the actions queue to handle most of the logic in your code.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for, and actually what I knew - Just hadn't thought of splitting it up the way you did. Nice work! I was actually trying to avoid the PriorityBlockingQueue as I didn't want the logic to rely on the collection, but the way you have done it is really elegant. And I just learnt about ReentrantLock conditions. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I remember why I didn't use PriorityBlockingQueue now! I didn't want the application to block on taking a job as - The program will wait until a network is up and then block on getting a job, if the internet goes down whilst it is waiting for a job and then a job is added, it could actually initiate a job with no internet available

Comment: I guess you could use peek() but then the queue will actually retrieve it which is a little inefficient. I solved this by simply adding another condition on your network lock, works great!